# How to restart supervisor for a Laravel deployment?

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord

I currently use a cron job to call `php artisan queue:work --once` every minute to work on my jobs queue in production.

I would like to use supervisor instead to handle my queues.

In the docs in the section of [supervisor-configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/queues#supervisor-configuration) it states:

> Since queue workers are long-lived processes, they will not pick up changes to your code without being restarted. So, the simplest way to deploy an application using queue workers is to restart the workers during your deployment process. You may gracefully restart all of the workers by issuing the queue:restart command:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

> This command will instruct all queue workers to gracefully "die" after they finish processing their current job so that no existing jobs are lost. **Since the queue workers will die when the queue:restart command is executed, you should be running a process manager such as Supervisor to automatically restart the queue workers.**

I don't understsand the last sentence. So lets say I have installed and configured the supervisor as described  [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#supervisor-configuration) and I manually logged into the server through ssh and started supervisor:

```
sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
```

Do I need to call `php artisan queue:restart` on deployment? If so, then this will only kill all current workers, how do I tell supervisor to restart the queue workers? Do I need to call `sudo supervisorctl restart laravel-worker:*` in the deployment after `php artisan queue:restart`?

Comment: Sometimes I need to run `sudo supervisorctl restart laravel-worker:*`, due to some of service worker not restarted. Even after I try to run `php artisan queue:restart`, some service worker are not restart. I don't know why. But, the point is, you definitely should restart your queue service after some code changes or some config changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled with this for quite some time.  It is a little confusing, and the docs tend to point to each other rather than explain how the whole system works.

The whole point of installing supervisor on your server is to automate the `queue` process within any Laravel apps running on the machine.  If you look at the example file on the help page you linked to, all it is doing is going into a specific Laravel instance and starting the queue.

When supervisor starts, it is the equivalent of:

```
php artisan queue:start
```

within your Laravel folder.  Supervisor is running the process.  But, you still have control to restart the queue, either through `sudo supervisorctl restart laravel-worker:*` or a `php artisan queue:restart` within a single Laravel folder.  You do not need to call a restart to supervisor if you are manually restarting the queue with the aritsan command - that would be redundant.  You can test this out by doing a restart of the queue and monitoring code changes updates, or looking at the queue itself to see that all jobs restart.

The 'gotcha' with all of this is that if you introduce new code and deploy it, you must remember to restart the queue for that instance.

To make things more complicated, but to eventually make it simple, take a look at [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/horizon), which basically takes the place of the supervisor in a way that is a bit easier to maintain.

Comment: So in short, I start supervisor once and add `artisan queue:reset` on each deploy?

Comment: Yes, `queue:restart` is important for any code changes.  And you can have supervisor autostart too.  Horizon is a nice package to automate some of it as well.  I have some of my apps deployed via git.  You can add a `post-merge` file to automate the `queue:restart` if you like as well.

Comment: @Watercayman Hello, but what should I do if there are no changes in a code, but changes in a db? Command takes values from DB and when I changed it, supervisor did not change anything. After that I tried to run php artisan queue:restart and unfortunately nothing.

Comment: @Aleks, could be a simple cache issue.  try `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear`.

Comment: @Watercayman Unfortunately, no. It takes new values only when I do supervisorctl restart

Comment: OK, at least that tells you that it is indeed a queue issue, and that narrows down the answer hugely.  supvsr might be running other workers?  Could be several things, but at least you know where to hunt

Comment: When I don't have a supervisor, then `php artisan queue:restart` will only kill current jobs, but not restart new processes, right?

Comment: It will kill current jobs for the your app (Laravel) that's running those jobs.  But it will start new processes if you have something in the queue or coming up I believe.  IE it starts the queue and looks to see if something needs to run.  If so, it starts the job.  else, it runs in the background and waits for the next job.